# How can I tell when to water my Chinese elm bonsai?

Tags: bonsai

I moved my Chinese elm bonsai from my office to home. In the office the soil was usually dry after 2 days without watering, so I'd water every 2 days, before it got dry.

Now, at home, the soil is never dry! Does that mean I should no longer water it?

I'm new to bonsais (or any gardening for that matter) and I'm following the rule that you should only water your bonsai if you realise the soil is getting dry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given where you are, now that temperatures have fallen, watering should be reduced - if your heating is not running at home while you're at the office, it may be too cold for your Elm, it requires temps between 15 (at a minimum) and 20 degrees C. It's obviously warmer in your office, and the plant uses more water in summer and early autumn, but now, its conditions have changed and the season has changed. It doesn't appreciate draughts either, so assuming it's not near a door that constantly opens and shuts, or a window that's open, don't water now until you can see the soil looks fairly dry.